# Validate a textbox in a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

Windows form application(.Net 3.5) I have a textbox and a button on the form.
I want to disable the button once the textbox is empty.
I don't want to use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202195/textbox-validation-in-a-windows-form). Because the button is still enabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event handler for [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx), simply determine if the text box contains any data.  If it does, enable it.  Otherwise, disable it.  Add your event handler and then implement something like the following,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button1.Enabled = !(textBox1.Text == String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Or: `button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text.Length>0`.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the on [text change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx)

check and see what textbox.text is like this

```
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.text))
 {
  Button1.enabled = false;
 }
```

Comment: TextBox *Text* property values will never be null.

Comment: Actually thats not true ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780819/c-sharp-winform-how-textbox-became-null-on-button-click-second-time

Comment: Actually it is.  Try setting a TextBox Text value to null and then inspecting the Text property.  It will be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable the textbox, then using textChanged:

```
if (textbox.Text == ""){
   button.Enabled = false;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Make `button1.Enabled = false;`

and add EventHandler to `textbox1.TextChanged = new System.EventHandler(SearchBoxTextChanged);`

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = (textBox1.Text.Trim() != string.Empty);
    }
```